# app crashes every time i try to upload a image into firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase

I'am trying to create a app for registering complaint on vehicle theft, in which the owner has to submit the vehicle document image. The image gets selected and is displayed in image button, but when I press submit to upload image into storage my app crashes. can anyone help me through this.

1. My code for selecting the image and uploading the image.

   ```
   private void uploadImage() {
   final StorageReference ref = mStorageRef.child("images/"+id);
   ref.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()        {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                   String url=uri.toString();
                   dem2=rootRef.child("Downloadurl");
                   dem2.child(id).setValue(url);
               }
           });
       }
   }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
   ```

   }

This is the logcat error that occurs  when "upload" method is called

> 2019-11-16 22:43:14.064 1382-1492/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: gIOPHAl
>   initialized 2019-11-16 22:43:14.295 1382-2052/? E/PackageManager:
>   testDefaultGrantsWithRemoteExceptions:android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.permission.gts 2019-11-16 22:43:15.125
>   28736-28736/? E/ACRA: Skipping ANR Detector for process:
>   com.instagram.android:mqtt 2019-11-16 22:43:26.214 1382-1478/?
>   E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{
>   mTimestamp=257068175 mSleepTimeMs=179685038 mIdleTimeMs=-179684977
>   mTxTimeMs[]=[271, 474, 86, 85, 1285] mRxTimeMs=23029 mEnergyUsed=0}
>   2019-11-16 22:43:29.708 528-528/? E/HWComposer:
>   presentAndGetReleaseFences: failed for display 0: NotValidated (7)
>   2019-11-16 22:43:31.074 28683-28797/com.example.rtgt_login
>   E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
>       An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
>        Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
>
> beginning of crash 2019-11-16 22:43:31.079 28683-28797/com.example.rtgt_login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   FirebaseStorage-Upload-1
>       Process: com.example.rtgt_login, PID: 28683
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in
>   /data/app/com.example.rtgt_login-GAD2_wYHG9BB_vFom1GNPg==/base.apk)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.getCurrentAuthToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:148)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:65)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:57)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:457)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:257)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:198)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:1106)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown
>   Source:2)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2019-11-16 22:43:31.112 1382-5720/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not
>   whiteListedcom.example.rtgt_login/com.example.rtgt_login.Complaint/1
>   2019-11-16 22:43:31.136 1382-1475/? E/PackageManager:
>   testDefaultGrantsWithRemoteExceptions:android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.permission.gts 2019-11-16 22:43:31.164 1382-2052/?
>   E/PackageManager:
>   testDefaultGrantsWithRemoteExceptions:android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.permission.gts 2019-11-16 22:43:31.165 1382-1939/?
>   E/PackageManager:
>   testDefaultGrantsWithRemoteExceptions:android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.permission.gts 2019-11-16 22:43:31.170 1382-11857/?
>   E/PackageManager:
>   testDefaultGrantsWithRemoteExceptions:android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.permission.gts 2019-11-16 22:43:31.170 1382-11857/?
>   E/PackageManager:
>   testDefaultGrantsWithRemoteExceptions:android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.permission.gts

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To encourage other users to help you with your issue, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please also provide the complete [stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: sorry couldn't upload the image i have included the logcat error that occurs bellow the code.